# Why is my eclipse not setting my background color?

Tags: java, awt

I have designed a code for a game. The problem is that the background won't change to any of my selected colors I have picked from graphics color library.

I need someone to figure this out with the code i have provided (please don't make a whole new code). idk why java/ eclipse won't display it??? am i missing something?? The program here should display a GUI with a background color blue. instead i get white.

```
public class MainApp extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8928635543572788908L;

    private static final int WIDTH= 648, HEIGHT= WIDTH/ 12 * 9;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running= false;

    public MainApp()
    {
        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "App", this);
    }
    public synchronized void start()
    {
        thread= new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running= true;
    }
    public void run()
    {
        long lastTime= System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks= 60.0;
        double ns= 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta= 0;
        long timer= System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames= 0;
        while(running){
            long now= System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now- lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime= now;
            while(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if(running)

            render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000)
            {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.print("FPS: " + frames);
                frames= 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    public synchronized void stop()
    {
        try
        {
            thread.join();
            running= false;
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public void tick()
    {

    }
    public void render()
    {
        BufferStrategy bs= this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs== null)
        {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g= bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainApp();
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you call `start`?

Comment: Start is in my Window class which i call in my constructor in the beginning..

Comment: new Window(arguments) when i call this my app.start(); starts to run.

Comment: Okay, make sure you're not getting an `IllegalStateException ` with the component not been attached to the native peer (ie, the Window not been visible before you try to create a `BufferStrategy`), because that's the first thing your code did when I got it working, but I was able to get it to run safely with a little bit of a tweak

Comment: I am not getting any errors. my FPS is working just my background won't show. how were you able to get it working?

Comment: JFrame frame= new JFrame(title);
  
  frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
  frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
  frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
  
  frame.setResizable(false);
  frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  frame.add(app);
  app.start();

Comment: this here is my window class

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: would you mind chatting with me ?? on the chat thing?

Comment: You can just do setBackground(Color.red);

Comment: that did not work setBackGround(Color.blue);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your codes a little messed up, you shouldn't be making a new instance of `Window` from `MainApp`, the `Window` should be creating it (IMHO).

Also, you should be overriding the `getPreferredSize` method the the `MainApp`, as this is what should be controlling the viewable size of the window, this way, when you use pack on the `JFrame`, it will ensure that the window is larger then the `preferredSize` of it's contents, allowing the frame decorations to wrap around the outside of it.

BUT, the main problem you have, is adding the `MainApp` to the `JFrame` AFTER it's already been made visible

The following works for me...

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainApp extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8928635543572788908L;

    private static final int WIDTH = 648, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 12 * 9;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    public MainApp() {
        new Window("App", this);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
        running = true;
    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if (running) {
                render();
            }
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.print("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {
            thread.join();
            running = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void tick() {

    }

    public void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainApp();
    }

    public static class Window {

        private Window(String title, MainApp app) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(app);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            app.start();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you MadProgrammer but can you somewhat explain again whats going on.. Im kind of slow? what was my major mistake? and was the major fix? Thank you so much. I did this code before and it worked on me but i retyped it to practice but it did not work.

Comment: also why do i get an error when it starts then it goes away?

Comment: I don't know about the error, but you might have a race condition between your thread and the window becoming visible. The major problem was adding the "app" to the frame after the frame was made visible, which meant the component wasn't getting laid out correctly, this is a very common mistake